# use "rewrite" and "try_files" together [Nginx]

Tags: nginx, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I removed the ".php" suffix at the end of the PHP files on the Nginx server with the following code, but this time I cannot send some data to the server.

```
try_files $uri/ $uri.html $uri.php$is_args$query_string;
```

Some links on the site are sent with Ajax, and the ".php" extension is not available at the end of these links. E.g; https://panel.example.com/app/controller/ajax/collect

For example, when I want to access the "/collect" file that I want to access via Ajax or directly, I get the error "File not found". Because I do "rewrite" with the code below and provide a clean URL.

```
rewrite ^/([^/]+)/([^/]+)?$ /index.php?cmd=$1&scd=$2 last;
rewrite ^/([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?cmd=$1 last;
```

Sample link: https://panel.example.com/[details|cat|profile]/[subPages(productID, username..)]

As a result, the above codes are correct and working, but not working at the same time together. How can I run these two codes at the same time?

[Nginx Conf. File](https://pastebin.com/03s90FQu)

Comment: Cross-site post on ServerFault: https://serverfault.com/questions/1088665/use-rewrite-and-try-files-together-nginx

Comment: @Emre6 Can you add your full configuration (excluding private details) to your question?

Comment: Hi @IvanShatsky , I updated my question content and you can access [this link](https://pastebin.com/03s90FQu)